# I can't get sound to work in Ubuntu 15. Could upgrading to 16 fix it?

Tags: upgrade, sound

I'm pretty sure the hardware works, since I was able to hear sound when I had CentOS on the same computer earlier, and also in an earlier edition of Ubuntu before that (again, on the same hardware).

Comment: Can you run `sudo aplay -l` in the terminal. Then, post the output. It will tell you if your sound card was found.